# How Orochimaru is still mentally active after being stabbed by Totsuka sword?

Tags: naruto

As per [Sword of Totsuka](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Sword_of_Totsuka) article on Naruto wiki,

> Those who are stabbed by the sword are drawn into the jar and trapped in a genjutsu-like "world of drunken dreams" for all eternity

If a person is stabbed by Totsuka sword, he gets caught in an eternal genjutsu, which means his mind can't be active anymore. But, how come Orochimaru is still mentally active? **I assume that, though he could get different bodies, the mind is the same for all.**

Comment: gentle reminder.....incase if my answer convinced you please do accept it..... would really appreciate on doing that.....

Answer (score 3):

The jutsu which Orochimaru used is called Juinjutsu. Orochimaru was unable to use Sage Mode and thus [had to create an alternative way to make use of Senjutsu](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Orochimaru%27s_Juinjutsu).

> In addition to his various test subjects, Orochimaru gave cursed seals to some of his most powerful and unique followers, either to enhance their abilities or to prepare them for becoming potential host bodies. To apply a cursed seal, Orochimaru bites the recipient, doing so with the aid of his sharp fangs and extendible neck. The seal then appears on the body of the victim near the puncture wound before causing them to lose consciousness.

Now try recalling the concept of Bunshin no Jutsu. When clones are created, it has mind of their own. As a result, when it is released, the original would get the details of clone's experience. **Clearly Orochimaru's technique is not Bunshin. It's much more evolved than that.** He shares a portion of his power in the host's body and tries to reside in the body. So naturally, it has a different mind.

Try recalling the incident during Kabuto and Sasuke fight. **After Orochimaru was revived from Anko Mitarashi's body by Uchiha Sasuke**, he said that he had been seeing the entire war from Anko's body, which clearly showed that he was mentally active inside the host's body.

#### Reference

- [**Orochimaru's Juinjutsu**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Orochimaru's_Juinjutsu)
- [**Anko Mitarashi**](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Anko_Mitarashi)